# AngularJS UI router's "resolve" fires twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I am using [angular ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to handle some routing on my frontend. This is what my routing code looks like.

```
// angular config

$stateProvider.state('app', {
    templateUrl: '/static/partials/home.html',
    controller: 'NavCtrl'
});

$stateProvider.state('app.reader', {
    url : '/reader/*path?start&end&column&page',
    templateUrl: '/static/partials/reader.html',
    resolve : {
        panelContent : [
            '$state', '$stateParams', '$http',
            function ($state, $stateParams, $http) {
                alert('resolving panel Content');
                return [];  // simplest thing possible to illustrate my point
            }
        ]
    },
    controller: 'ReaderCtrl'
});

/// etc etc

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/reader/');
```

My html makes use of multiple nested views, I'll try and illustrate as best I can

index.html

```
<html>
    <div ui-view></div>     <!-- /static/partials/home.html gets injected here -->
</html>
```

/static/home.html

```
<html>
    <!-- some side bar stuff -->

    <!-- reader -->
    <div ui-view></div>    <!-- /static/partials/reader.html gets injected here -->
</html>
```

So I've got multiple levels of nesting going on

```
-- index.html
    -- home.html
        -- reader.html
```

Now, when I load the page for the first time, my alert message

```
alert('resolving panel Content');
```

fires just once.. that makes sense. However, let's say I click "next page" inside my pagination..

```
<!-- inside /static/partials/reader.html -->   

<uib
    pagination total-items= "totalItems"
    ng-model= "pageNumber"
    ng-change= "pageUpdate"
    max-size= "maxPageNumbersDisplayed"
></uib>
```

this eventually fires a function inside my "ReaderCtrl"

```
$scope.pageUpdate(page) {
    $state.go( '.', {page: page}); 
}
```

This updates the url, from going to something like this

```
/#/reader/<my path>
```

to something like this

```
/#/reader/<my_path>?page=2
```

Now for the part that has me tearing my hair out.

I get back to the "resolve" code block in the reader section of my routing.

The alert message happens twice.

By doing a bit of debugging in the web console, I discovered that the order goes

```
 1) alert message in resolve
 2) travel through the entirety of ReaderCtrl
 3) lots and lots of angular calls
 4) alert message (2nd time)
 5) travel through entirety of ReaderCtrl a second time.
```

You might be inclined to know what is going on in NavCtrl, but I am not making any calls there. All that is in NavCtrl are functions that ReaderCtrl can inherit, in order to update the scope for /static/partials/home.html

So really, it appears as though I am stuck on step 3 here.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why my resolve block appears to be firing twice?

edit:

after a bit more debugging, I have seemed to figure out that the order goes something like this, starting right after the "updatePage" function executes.

```
1) first "resolving message"
    -- the url has not yet changed
2) second "resolving message"
    -- the url appears to have changed very shortly before this message
```

So, I guess my question now is...
why does

```
$state.go('.', args);
```

NOT change the url before the first alert fires, but DOES change the url at/near the second alert?

edit 2: could not end up fixing my issue, so I sort of hacked around it for the time being... I essentially made a function that did what I assume $state.go() was doing behind the scenes, and constructed the url.

```
function _mk_url(args) {

    var url = "/reader";

    var pageNumber = args.pageNumber || 1;
    url += "?page=" + pageNumber;

    var columns = args.columns || [];
    columns.forEach(function(d) {
        url += "&column=" + d;
    });

    //etc..

    return url;
}

var args = {"columns" : ["a", "b", "c"], "pageNumber" : 2};
var url = _mk_url(args);
$location.url(url);
```

Comment: Just from reading I assume the issue is with a state change in the `ReaderCtrl` and it is rerendering. It then resolves the route again to get an route params.

Comment: I added a few more alert lines, and I found out that 1) the first resolve is called 2) then the url changes 3) the next resolve fires. So it appears that the first $state.go( ... ) triggers the route/resolve, without actually changing the path. Then when the path ACTUALLY changes, the resolve is triggered again.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve Did you try using the `$stateChangeSuccess` which only fires after?

Comment: I tried using notify inside $state.go('.', args, {notify : true})

thinking that would alert the state change, but it didn't work. What did you mean by use $stateChangeSuccess

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem and found out it was because I was calling my resolve function manually somewhere else in the code. Search your code for `panelContent()` and you may find where it's getting triggered again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd got this problem. The reason was in my html template. I used `ui-sref` directive in both child and parent elements

`<li ui-sref="{{r.name}}" ng-class="vm.isCurrent(r)" ng-repeat="r in vm.settingsRoutes">
    <span ui-sref="{{r.name}}" ng-bind-html="r.title"></span>
 </li>`

so when I clicked on `span`, I fired `stateChange` twice.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same bug. 
And I found that I was changed `$stateParams` in one of the resolve functions. 
The solution is make a copy from this object and then do what you want with a copy.

```
resolve: {

      /** @ngInject */
      searchParams: function ($stateParams) {
        let params = angular.copy($stateParams); // good

        // good: 
        if (params.pending === undefined) {
          params.pending = true;
        }

        // bad: 
        if ($stateParams.redirect === 'true') {
          $stateParams.pending = false; // this line changing the URL
        }
        return params;
      },
```

}